# Shell script doesn't change to directory passed as parameter

Tags: shell, unix

I am making a sort of a deployment script. Its a very simple git pull based deployment. 
I need it to accept two parameters: the app to be deployed and the type of server(staging, testing, production). So I wrote the script with a function for each app

```
./deploy.sh <appname> <server>
```

--

```
#deploy.sh
app1(){
        echo $2 #Empty
        cd /srv/www/app1/$2 #


        git pull origin master

}
case $1 in
        "app1") app1;;
esac
```

Now when I run the script with the following command `./deploy.sh app1 staging`.
The script only navigates to the `/srv/www/app1` directory, not `/srv/www/app1/staging`
When I echo $2, nothing is displayed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you use `$2` in `app1` it tries to interpret the arguments passed to `app1` which is empty, so you need to pass it as an argument to `app1`. Try this:

```
app1(){
        echo $1 #Empty
        cd /srv/www/app1/$1 #


        git pull origin master

}
case $1 in
        "app1") app1 $2;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into scope.  Each function a shell script can be passed arguments.  The `app()` function is looking for $2 as an argument to itself.  There have been no args passed, so $2 equates to "".  If you use the script below you should be fine, passing $2 to app1 in the case.

```
#deploy.sh
app1(){
        echo $1 #Empty
        cd /srv/www/app1/$1 #


        git pull origin master

}
case $1 in
    "app1") app1 $2 ;;
esac
```